# Total convergence of a series of functions with $\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

I'm trying to solve this problem about series of functions:

Study the pointwise and uniform convergence of the following series:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\sqrt n - \sin(x)}{n^2x^n}\right)^2$$

I studied the pointwise convergence and I got that the series converges pointwise in

> $$(-\infty,-1] , [1,+\infty)$$

Then I tried to study the total convergence in  $[1,+\infty)$ using the M-test :
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt n +(- \sin(x))}{n^2x^n}\right)^2\le\left(\frac{\sqrt n + 1}{n^2x^n}\right)^2<\left(\frac{\sqrt n+1}{n^2}\right)^2=M(n)$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M(n) <+\infty$ the series converges totally in $[1,+\infty)$ (I am not really sure about this).
When I try to study the total convergence in $(-\infty,-1]$ I can't get to the same result using the M-test. I tried using the Weiestrass test but studying the first derivative gets me to an inequality involving sin cos and x, and I'm not sure I can solve it. What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks, and sorry if my english is not perfect.

Comment: I am not sure what you call "total" convergence, but you can investigate absolute convergence in same way for $|x| \geqslant 1$.

Comment: Total convergence means that there exists a convergent numeric sequence Mn such that |fn(x)|≤Mn for all n∈N. I'm sorry, but in italian we express this concept with the term "convergenza totale". –

Comment: It is called uniform convergence in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\ne 0$ and $n\ge1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\left(\frac{\sqrt n-\sin(x)}{n^2x^n}\right)^2\right|&\le \frac{(\sqrt n+1)^2}{n^4x^{2n}}\\\\
&\le \frac{4}{n^3 x^{2n}}
\end{align}$$

And for $|x|\ge 1$, we find that

$$\left|\left(\frac{\sqrt n-\sin(x)}{n^2x^n}\right)^2\right|\le \frac{4}{n^3}$$

Now applying the M-test, we find that for $|x|\ge 1$, the series of interest converges uniformly.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Can I ask you why you used 4/n^3 instead of 1/n^3 ? thanks again

Comment: You are certainly welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that for $n\ge 1$, $\sqrt{n} +1\ge 2\sqrt{n}$, and thus $(\sqrt{n}+1)^2\le 4n$.

Comment: Last line, first inequality is reversed. And .... I'm doing fine thanks, dodging the Delta pretty well so far.

Comment: @zhw. Glad to hear you're doing well.  Which inequality is reversed??  All are upper bounds for the case $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: Right, I was commenting on your comment: You have $\sqrt n+1\ge 2\sqrt n.$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, that is a careless typo.